# How do I remove rake test errors in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have encountered some errors while running rake test, though my app is working fine.
I wanted to remove those errors for future assistance.
I get the following lines of messages:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have posted the stack trace, but not the error itself.

Comment: The following error is coming 7 different times in different instances. So if I get a solution for 1, then I can do for the rest:
@lulalala the error is->
test_should_create_product(ProductsControllerTest):
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 3 column 1

Comment: I guess your yaml is wrong. Run it against http://yamllint.com/